# To count the comparisons in QuickSort, small size data is OK, but large size(like over 50 ints)would take a long time, why?

Tags: c++, quicksort

Following code  runs correctly when the size of array below 40, but larger size makes it run very long time.
please tell me why it work like this. Thank you very much.
why the website always tells me to add some more details.

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int Quicksort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
    int p = arr[l];
    int i = l+1;
    for (int j = l+1; j <=r; j++){
        if (arr[j] < p){
             int tem = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[j];
             arr[j] = tem;
             i +=1;
        }
    }

    arr[l] = arr[i-1];
    arr[i-1] = p;

    int count = r-l;//each subarray has (r-l) comparisons

    if (r-l ==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        int j =i-1;
        if (j>l){
            Quicksort(arr, l,j-1);
            count +=Quicksort(arr,l,j-1);
        }
        if (j <r){
            Quicksort(arr, j+1,r);
            count += Quicksort(arr, j+1,r);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin >>n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin >>arr[i];
    }
    cout<<Quicksort(arr, 0, n-1)<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] <<' ';
    }
    cout <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation; this is *very* hard to read.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it. Sorry, this is my first time to use this.

Comment: I've just noticed (now that I can read it properly) that the code is C++, not C. I'll change the tag this time, but please use an appropriate one for the language in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the leftmost element of the partition as your pivot. This has a worst case scenario when the array is already sorted.

"But my array isn't already sorted!" you say. Well, look at these lines of code:

```
    if (j <r){
        Quicksort(arr, j+1,r);
        count += Quicksort(arr, j+1,r);
    }
```

You are calling QuickSort twice, the second time you call it, *the partition is already sorted*. Leading to a worst case scenario for the second call.

Comment: Actually, it is homework. The teacher required I must choose the first element as pivot. But you solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your two consecutive calls to Quicksort with the same arguments and poor choice of pivot  will result in exponential runtime. It can be tricky to write a good Quicksort algorithm, but there are excellent algorithm texts, such as by Robert Sedgewick, which have good implementations of Quicksort.

On the other hand, you can use the generic sort algorithm provided by the C++ STL.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        arr.push_back(val);
    }

    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    for (int x : arr)
        cout << x << ' ';

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is homework. It is required that I have to choose the first element as pivot and count the comparisons. However, you solve my problem. I delete one call of Quicksort. It works. Thanks a lot!